# Como inserir EMOJI - SMARTFONES no banco de dados MySQL com PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, android, mysql, html5

Bem, como a pergunta é bem auto explicativa irei somente reforçar a pergunta.

Tenho um sistema APP de conversa, que através do **HTML**, mando para **PHP** com `Ajax`, mas se o usurário tentar inserir algum *emoji* (emotion) do seu aparelho no banco de dados ele recebe: "????" como mensagem.

Como posso alterar isso para que receba algum tipo de código para cada emotion e no site liste de acordo com o valor dele?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pergunta muito interessante. A resposta curta seria: Converta o *character set* da sua tabela para **`utf8mb4`**, já que este formato aceita todos os caracteres Unicode.

Comment: Já testei desse modo, mas não deu certo..

Comment: Mesmo mudando sua coluna ou tabela para utf8mb4 não deu certo? `emojicolumn VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`? Na tabela: `ALTER TABLE tabela CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`?

Comment: Além de mudar o charset, execute esse SQL antes de todas das chamadas envolvendo emoticon: `SET NAMES utf8mb4`;.

Comment: Como está sendo feita está chamada ajax? Pode ser nisto o problema também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viva,

Resumidamente, terá de converter os dados adicionados pelos utilizadores tendo em conta o tipo de dispositivo usado. O mais usual é ter de converter para Unified. Deixo aqui o link com o código pronto a funcionar. Diga caso tenha problemas.

Veja aqui `http://code.iamcal.com/php/emoji/` .

Answer (score -3):

Uma maneira mais simples é adicionar o emoji dentro da mensagem como um `span` com uma classe específica no CSS que corresponda à ele. No banco de dados, salve a mensagem normalmente como HTML.